# Handle transition on absolutely position element pushing other elements

Tags: javascript, css

I have a responsive nav that expands down into the content below. Even with `position: absolute`, while the transition occurs it still pushes down the lower content. The problem is with the transition.

My idea to solve it was to add a class to the lower content whenever the navbar gets clicked. This would momentarily add absolute positioning to all the lower content so it does not get in the way of the dropdown.

Beside all the complexity this would take, I am using react and react-bootstrap and this [dropdown](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/), last one in the list. This does not have a `onTransitionEnd` event, so I don't know how to remove this added class once I've added it. I thought after the dropdown ends but without this event not sure how to do.

This is a simple problem but I am not sure how to fix it without rewriting the code. I've tried repositioning the lower content but no matter what I do the dropdown hits it, or its margin.  Some solutions say `z-index` should solve but that did not work.

If there is no solution I'm happy to hear ways to redesign.

I've made a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-cache-p0xrn) with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit to get you along the right path:

```
.top-navbar {
  align-self: flex-end;
  height: 4em;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.navbar-nav {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  background-color: red;
}
```

The only thing that's left is making it so the button doesn't bump up/down which shouldn't be too hard to figure out